# chrome window.open(url '_blank') opens new window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I try to open 3 new tabs (at the same time) via chrome, EI, firefox, each tab will return a file.
ie and mozilla open 3 new tabs (it is ok).
chrome opens 1 tab and two windows.

Script:
    window.open(url '_blank') or  window.open(url '_tab') 
behaviour is the same

Is there any way to open 3 new tabs in chrome ?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371285/how-to-open-multiple-tabs-from-one-html-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is up to the settings of your browser. You can't modify this with code.

Answer (score -2):

No, JavaScript has no knowledge of tabs. Generally you want to avoid `window.open` altogether for exactly this reason. - stay with regular links instead and possibly don't force a new tab/window on the user (he has a middle mouse button anyway).